# varnish restrict access by sending header

Tags: security, header, varnish

I am using Varnish to serve a website, and not very used to it.
 I would like to be able to use a maintenance mode on the site.
When maintenance is enabled, only a few ips would be able to access the site, the others visitors have to see the maintenance page.

I already have a ip whitelist set in the vcl file, to restrict purge or admin access, so I'd like to avoid to copy the same whitelist in the website code to test if access is allowed or not during maintenance.

Would it be possible and secure to use varnish for analyzing the IP and setting a custom header like this if the ip is in the whitelist ?

```
  set req.http.X-Ip-Whitelisted = "1";
```

Then, this header would be tested on the website to display maintenance or not.

Or do I have to test the visitor ip on the website side ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add part of vcl where the ip whitelist is defined? And where PURGE or admin access restriction rules are applied? Change real values as needed, but it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: sounds fine to me

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The part where the ip whitelist is defined is acl admin. There are several parts in the vcl file to restrict access or purge using this list with client.ip ~ admin so I don't know if it's relevant. Like :  sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache" && client.ip ~ admin) {
        purge;
        return(restart);
    }
}